# Build array from attribute of multiple elements

Tags: jquery

I have html like this:

```
<li class="select2-selection__choice" title="10" data-select2-id="22">
  <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>
   10
</li>
```

I need to find every `li` with this class: `select2-selection__choice` and I need the only value of the `title` attribute. Is it possible?

I can have a lot of these `li` elements, but they have different values. I need every value of them in an array.

Comment: What attempt have you made to achieve this? Try http://api.jquery.com/map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Create an empty jQuery array

2.Iterate over each `li` element which has`select2-selection__choice` class using [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

3.Get the title value using [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and then convert it to an integer using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and push it to your array using [.push()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

Do like this:-

```
var title_array = [];

$('li.select2-selection__choice').each(function(){
  title_array.push(parseInt($(this).attr('title')));
});
console.log(title_array);
```

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var title_array = [];

  $('li.select2-selection__choice').each(function(){
    title_array.push(parseInt($(this).attr('title')));
  });
  console.log(title_array);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="10" data-select2-id="22">
      <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>10
  </li>
  <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="11" data-select2-id="23">
      <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>11
  </li>
  <li class="select2-selection__choice" title="12" data-select2-id="24">
    <span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>12
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @wenus  glad to help you :):). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use map(), *and consider using trim() on the title*.

```js
let d = $('.select2-selection__choice').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('title') // .trim() to get nicer results
}).get();
console.log(d);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="select2-selection__choice" title="
                                        10
                                    " data-select2-id="22"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span> 10
</li>
<li class="select2-selection__choice" title="
                                        10
                                    " data-select2-id="22"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span> 10
</li>
<li class="select2-selection__choice" title="
                                        10
                                    " data-select2-id="22"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span> 10
</li>
```